# Get employees which have smaller salary than any of those who sold more than one order

Tags: sql, join, select, group-by

Sorry for long title but I wanted to explain the situation.

My brains are almost exploding I have tried this for five hours now, and I don't get it. Got just a big headache.

I want to get those employees which haec smaller salary than anyone of those who has sold one or more orders. There is two tables `EMPLOYEES` and `ORDERS`.

`EMPLOYEES` have these columns; First name, Last name, Social security number, Salary.

`ORDERS` have these columns; Social security number, OrderID

This is best solution so far.

```
SELECT H.SOCSECNUM, H.LASTNAME, H.FIRSTNAME, H.SALARY
FROM EMPLOYEES H
WHERE H.SALARY < ALL(SELECT COUNT(T.ORDERID)
                     FROM ORDERS T
                     WHERE  H.SOCSECNUM = T.SOCSECNUM
                     HAVING COUNT(T.ORDERID) > 0
                     );
```

I understand this like get social security number, name and salary of all employees which have smaller salary than anyone who sold more than 0 orders.

Am I stupid or what is wrong in that? Now this prints all employees which have 0 orders. If i change 0 -> 1 it prints all employees which have one or less orders.

Comment: Looks to me like you're comparing a salary to a count of order IDs.

Comment: Please tag your question with the database that you are using.

Comment: Would the orders table only have those ssn who made an order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that's the query you wanted to write:

```
select e.*
from employees e
where h.salary < all (
    select h1.salary
    from employees e1
    where exists (select 1 from orders o1 where o1.socsecnum = e1.socsecnum)
)
```

The subquery returns the list of salaries of employees that performed at least one sale. You can then use `all` to filter the table against that.

You could also use aggregation:

```
select e.*
from employees e
where h.salary < (
    select min(h1.salary)
    from employees e1
    where exists (select 1 from orders o1 where o1.socsecnum = e1.socsecnum)
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need the number of orders and salary for employees.  This is helpful in one row. So, use `JOIN`:

```
select e.*, numorders
from employees e left join
     (select o.socseqnum, count(*) as numorders
      from orders o
      group by o.socseqnum
     ) o
     on e.socseqnum = o.socseqnum;
```

Then, I would use window functions to get the minimum salary for the one-order employees and use a comparison to that:

```
select eo.*
from (select e.*, o.numorders,
             min(case when numorders = 1 then e.salary end) over () as min_salary_1order
      from employees e left join
           (select o.socseqnum, count(*) as numorders
            from orders o
            group by o.socseqnum
           ) o
           on e.socseqnum = o.socseqnum
     ) eo
where salary < min_salary_1order
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `uncorrelated subquery`

```
select *
from employees 
where salary < (select min(salary) 
                from employees 
                where socsecnum in (select socsecnum  
                                    from orders 
                                    where socsecnum  is not null));
```